# Yii2 i18n: Can't change language

Tags: php, yii2, internationalization

My sites content is in russian. 
In my view file I have, for example:

```
<span><?=Yii::t('app','Главная')?></span>
```

In my parameters.php file:

```
'languages' => [
    'ru' => 'russian',
    'en' => 'english',
]
```

To switch language I'm writing:

```
<?foreach(Yii::$app->params['languages'] as $key => $language):?>
    <li class="language" id="<?=$key?>"><?=$language?></li>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Created JS file:

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click','.language',function(){
    var lang = $(this).attr('id');

    $.post('index.php?r=site/language',{'lang':lang},function(data){
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

});

In common\config\main.php:

```
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                //'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'ru',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Then I have in frontend\messages\en\app.php:

```
return [
    'Главная'=>'Home',
];
```

As the result, when I open my project, by default instead of 'Главная' I have 'Home'. And when I click 'russian' or 'english', page reloads but doesn't change anything. I want to display by default russian language, and switch it in english by clicking on 'english' link. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Check this [guide](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/i18n-selecting-application-language/).